# Saving Facebook profile picture and username Android

Tags: android, facebook

I've been working on a simple app for android - and i'm trying to login using Single Sign-On using the Facebook Android SDK.

I'm trying to save the profile picture and username. I'm not quite sure what's wrong - but nothing seems to happen after I Sign In on Facebook.

Here's my code:

```
public class fbLogin extends Activity {
 Facebook facebook = new Facebook("MY-APP-ID");
 private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
 public boolean flag=false;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fblogin_screen);
        mPrefs=getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String acces_token=mPrefs.getString("acces_token",null);
        long expires=mPrefs.getLong("acces_expires", 0);

        if(acces_token!=null)
        {
            facebook.setAccessToken(acces_token);
        }
        if(expires!=0)
        {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        if(!facebook.isSessionValid())
        {
        facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {

            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                flag=true;
                 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                 editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                 editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                 editor.commit();

            }

            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

            public void onError(DialogError e) {}

            public void onCancel() {}
        });
    } else{
        flag=true;
        }

        if(flag==true)
        {
            try {
                JSONObject me = new JSONObject(facebook.request("me"));
                String id=me.getString("id");
                String userName=me.getString("username");
                ImageView picture;
                TextView usr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userName);
                picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
                URL image_value= new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/" + userName + "/pictures" );
                Bitmap profPict=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
                picture.setImageBitmap(profPict);
                usr.setText(userName);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this
URL image_value= new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/" + userName + "/pictures" );
to this
URL image_value= new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/" + userName + "/picture" );

Comment: Thanks -- this was the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Put this:

```
if(flag==true)
        {
            try {
                JSONObject me = new JSONObject(facebook.request("me"));
                String id=me.getString("id");
                String userName=me.getString("username");
                ImageView picture;
                TextView usr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userName);
                picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
                URL image_value= new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/" + userName + "/pictures" );
                Bitmap profPict=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
                picture.setImageBitmap(profPict);
                usr.setText(userName);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

In it's own method called getInfo(), then in your dialog listener call getInfo() like so

```
facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {

            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                flag=true;
                 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                 editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                 editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                 editor.commit();
                 //We're authorized so getInfo();
                 getInfo();
            }

            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

            public void onError(DialogError e) {}

            public void onCancel() {}
        });
```

Now, in the Facebook SDK, there's a class called Utility. Set LOGGING = true.
Give it another go and watch the logs. The logs from facebook may say there's a mismatch between your app hash and the facebook app. Copy the hash in the log, go to your facebook app, check the box for android application and paste the hash in the corresponding field.

Comment: I have already tried this - but still does not work! Also my app is loging in facebook and the userName and picture are retrived (I've checked) - the only problem is that the UI doesn't seem to update after loging in!